# Node Js :Displaying images in mongodb and nodeJS gives broken image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

So after going throgh some documents I did the following
This is my model;

```
var doctorSchema = new Schema({
         img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
```

> `This is my backend controller`

```
function uploadPhoto(req, res, next) {
  var imgPath = "C:/emed/public/logo.png";
      var a = new Doctor;
      a.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
      a.img.contentType = 'image/png';
      //console.log(a.img.data);
      a.save(function (err, a) {
        if (err) console.log('success');
        console.error('saved img to mongo');

      });
      Doctor.findById(a, function (err, doc) {
        if (err)console.log("error");
        var base64 = (doc.img.data.toString('base64'));
        res.send(base64);
```

And this my angular success function where I store it with a scope variable and display image to my view b.
But I am getting a broken image ?...Can anyone help me with this.

```
.success(function (data) {
        $scope.image = data;
        console.log(data);
```

My view in jade template is like this.

```
 img(ng-src = '{{image}}' err-src="/assets/img/user.jpg" alt="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't constructed a data URI

`data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>`

```
Doctor.findById(a, function (err, doc) {
   if (err)console.log("error");
   var base64 = doc.img.data.toString('base64');
   res.send('data:'+doc.img.contentType+';base64,' + base64);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot perfectly working..Can you please tell me If I am going wrong way, I am presently working to store images in database currently they are stored in local directories using multer.

Comment: 1. Why do you even migrate your static files from file system to the database? Is this really needed?

Comment: 2. Why are you sending the data base64 encoded? Why not send raw binary data.
3. Why are you loading the image via AJAX. Set the URL (rest endpoint I guess) directly in the markup as source.